# Java 7 and 8 install problem

Tags: java

I installed java following this tutorial that and the tutorial made me go to this certain file with path variables or something. To play Runescape I need java 7 so I need to switch. I have installed java 7 with a tutorial on this site but im still on jjava 8 for some reason. How exactly do i get java 7 enabled for this game?

The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZB3Iy7Lve4

Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Which tutorial in particular?

Comment: @muru can't find it in my history but i had to extract java into it's wn folder in /usr/lib/java/ . I then opened some PATH file

Comment: @muru Found it! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZB3Iy7Lve4

Answer (score 0):

You can do the installation with this PPA

Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy)

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu saucy main
```

With this command you can switch between the different methods:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: @nubb Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓).